# How can i click on card view on one activity and open new activity with data from Firebase

Tags: java, android

I have one activity which connects with database and all my data is coming, but I want when I click on one Card view to open data from data Card.
I have like on the first-page category and when I click on one I want to get all projects that are in that category.
I'm still learning (on my own) and this is the first problem I can't solve by myself.
Plesa helps me.
I have tried everything I can find online.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

        ImageButton imageButton;

        private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        private CollectionReference firemRef = db.collection("kategorije");

        private FirmeAdapter adapter;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpRecyclerView();






 }

          private void setUpRecyclerView(){
         Query query= firemRef.orderBy("logo",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
         FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Firme> options = new 
         FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Firme>()
            .setQuery(query,Firme.class)
            .build();
         adapter= new FirmeAdapter(options);

          RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
          recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



       @Override
       protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       adapter.startListening();
}

       @Override
       protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
}
        public void onClickButton (View view){

        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,BeautyIzbornik.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


}


}
```

My ADAPTER

```
    import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    public class FirmeAdapter extends  FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Firme, FirmeAdapter.FirmeHolder> {






        /**
         * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore         Query.  See {@link
         * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
         *
         * @param options
         */
        public FirmeAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Firme>         options) {

            super(options);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FirmeHolder holder, int         position, @NonNull final Firme model) {
            holder.naziv.setText(model.getNaziv());
            holder.setLogo(model.getLogo());


        }        

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FirmeHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup,         int i) {
            View v =         LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.firme_item,
                    viewGroup,false);
            return new FirmeHolder(v);






        }


        class FirmeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageButton imageButton;
            TextView naziv;


            public FirmeHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                naziv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.naziv);
                imageButton =itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo);



            }
            public void setLogo(String logo) {
                Picasso.get().load(logo).into(imageButton);
            }




        }        


    }
```

My Activity with my data

```
    public class Firme {

        public String logo;
        public String naziv;
        public String url;



        public Firme ( ) {

        }

        public Firme (String naziv, String logo , String url){
            this.logo= logo;
            this.naziv= naziv;
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getLogo() {
            return logo;
        }

        public String getNaziv() {
            return naziv;
        }
        public void setLogo(String logo){
            this.logo = logo;
        }

        public String getUrl(){
            return url;
        }
        public void setUrl(String url){
            this.url=url;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read this. https://jonfhancock.com/your-viewholders-are-dumb-make-em-not-dumb-82e6f73f630c Create smart viewholders.

Comment: can you help me more....im  still learning...its little to tehnical for me

Comment: Read this as well https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/ . This will show you how to setup click lister for each item in the `RecyclerView`. 1. You need to get the data from firebase, then store it locally in a variable in the Activity or into a SQLite Database. The `RecyclerView` can not hook up magically to the Firebase Query directly. So you pass in the data array of an object then work with that data. 2. If your data is updated or needs updating, you again update the SQLite data or replace the local variable in your Activity then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the Adapter.

Comment: Guys im sorry i think you dont understand me i dont know where tu put this code...i try everthing....can you pleas explain me step by step where to put code

Comment: Please have a look at this project https://github.com/mxy1228/RecylerViewDemo
Compare what you have, and what you want. This project includes everything you need

Comment: Guys i need help this answers didnt help me...so let me explain.
I have one activity (it works perfect) with recycler view and i populated it with card view (data from Firestore) and everything works fine.
And now i want when i press one Card view to open another activity and in that activity to have data from that category of Card view...can you help me.In FIrestorer i have Colections that have same name as that Card view and i wont to open that collection on press on Card view.I hope i expalin it well enough to someone to help me...PLS

Comment: in `FirmeHolder` below `imageButton =itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo);` add `imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(imageButton.getContext(), "Clicked card!",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});` Once you see the toast message when you click on the card view then add a method to `FirmeHolder` to set the card view data `public setFireData(...)` in the method, you set a local variable. Then call setfiredata in `OnBindViewholder` See here http://pasted.co/f5899b0c

Comment: when i add this code my app doesnt work at all...it crash wont start...before this code my app works just wont fill new activity with thata from collection on whic i click

Comment: Please don't waste further time and go do an Android Course on https://www.pluralsight.com/

Answer (score 0):

you have to perform a click listener on `RecyclerView` item : 
Since each item has its own data , you should use this data to show the adequate information :
This how to implement a click listener for `RecyclerView`

In your `RecyclerView.Adapter` simply create an interface you can use.

```
private onItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

public interface onItemClickListener {
    void onItemClickListener(View view, int position, MyData myData);
}
```

In this case mItemClickListener is a global variable inside your adapter and the two methods go inside your adapter, too.

Then inside your ViewHolder apply a click listener to your itemView with itemView.setOnClickListener(this) (or whatever component you want clicked to retrieve the data)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mItemClickListener != null) {
        mItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(view, getAdapterPosition(), my_data.get(getAdapterPosition()));
    }
}
```

This will then pass the view that has been clicked, the position of said view and the object that is contained in your list within that position.

So in your Activity, you can then just simply call the interface.

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CustomAdapter.onItemItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position, MyData data) {
    //do on item click functionality here
    }
});
```

Comment: I still do not know where to put this code you told me to.....i try everything and it still does not work